# "Object doesn't support property or method 'shift'" in IE on Focus to JQuery Datepicker (Only after month/year is changed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a JQuery Datepicker using an AngularJS Directive, the datepiker works fine in Chrome/FireFox/Edge, but semi-works in IE.

The issue is the datepicker calendar will appear when you enter the input, you can pick a date, it closes, pick another, fine. But only if the date is for the current month/year, as soon as you change the Month or Year you can pick a date initially and it will appear in the input, but any subsequent attempts to make the calendar appear fail, clicking into the input results in the console error:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'shift'

```js
var App = angular.module('App', ["ui.bootstrap"]).config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {   

}]);

App.controller('Form', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $filter) {});

App.directive('datepicker', function ($timeout) {
  var linker = function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      scope: {
          myval: '='
      }
      $timeout(function () {
          $(element).datepicker({
              dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
              yearRange: '1900:+0',
              defaultDate: new Date(2000, 0, 1),
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true,
              //showAnim: "fold",
              onSelect: function (date) {
                  ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                  scope.$apply();
              },
              beforeShow: function (element, datepicker) {
                  if (attrs.minDate) {
                      angular.element(element).datepicker("option", "minDate", attrs.minDate);
                  }
                  if (attrs.maxDate) {
                      angular.element(element).datepicker("option", "maxDate", attrs.maxDate);
                  }
              }
          });
      });
  };

  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      transclude: true,
      link: linker,
  };

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="App">
<div ng-controller="Form">
<input datepicker id="DPID" type="text" min-date="-43800" max-date="-4840" ng-model="Date1" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

Comment: I edited your question to contain a snippet. Could you please make it runnable with whatever initialization you perform, so it becomes verifiable and debugabble by others?

Comment: @Tschallacka I've tried, but I've not done that in question before, I've got it to not error, but the datepicker doesn't work.

Comment: The thing is, for this question to work we need a minimal verifyable example that reproduces the problem. It seems like you're lacking the ui.bootstrap module, you might need to load that one also.

Comment: Also the code needs the `ng-app="App"` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduce the problem on my side, it seems that the issue is related to the JQuery version, you are using the JQuery 3.4.0 version. Please try to use the following JQuery reference:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem.
After changing to jQuery 3.4.1, the error no longer occurs.

Comment: If using jQuery 3.0+, upgrading to 3.4.1 will solve this issue. See here: https://blog.jquery.com/2019/05/01/jquery-3-4-1-triggering-focus-events-in-ie-and-finding-root-elements-in-ios-10

Answer (score 0):

The version 3.0 of the jQuery JavaScript framework, [is] the first version that features absolutely no workarounds for old Internet Explorer browsers (IE6-8).<sup>[1](https://news.softpedia.com/news/jquery-3-0-released-and-other-javascript-news-505064.shtml)</sup>

From Microsoft:<sup>[2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17454)</sup>

> Beginning January 12, 2016, only the most current version of Internet Explorer available for a supported operating system receives technical support and security updates, as shown in the following table:
>
> ```
>  Windows Desktop Operating Systems   Internet Explorer Version
>  ---------------------------------   -------------------------
>  Windows Vista SP2 *                 Internet Explorer 9
>  Windows 7 SP1                       Internet Explorer 11
>  Windows 8.1 Update                  Internet Explorer 11
>  Windows 10**                        Internet Explorer 11
> ```
>
> *This product is no longer in support. See the Lifecycle site for end of support dates and migration information.
>
> **Windows 10 features Microsoft Edge. Microsoft recommends using Microsoft Edge as your default browser and supports Internet Explorer 11 for backward compatibility.